# "error: node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js: Unexpected token 'export'"

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, babeljs, node-modules

I'm having a problem with my Expo project. 
When trying to run my app with `yarn start`, I'm facing this error:

```
Android Bundling failed 449ms
error: node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Here is my App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "./config/firebaseConfig";
import { IntroductionAnimationScreen } from "./introduction_animation";
// screens
import {
  PlantDetail,
  Welcome,
  Signup,
  Login,
  Profile,
  ChatBot,
  Settings,
  ExpertHome,
  CourseList,
  Cources,
} from "./screens";
// Tab Navigator
import Tabs from "./navigation/tabs";
// Font
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";

const theme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    border: "transparent",
  },
};

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (authUser) => {
      if (authUser) {
        // User is signed in
        setUser(authUser);
      } else {
        // User is signed out
        setUser(null);
      }
    });

    // Unsubscribe from the listener when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    "Roboto-Light": require("./assets/fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf"),
    "Roboto-Black": require("./assets/fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf"),
    "Roboto-Bold": require("./assets/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"),
    "Roboto-Regular": require("./assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"),
  });

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
        initialRouteName={user ? "HomeTabs" : "Welcome"}
      >
        {/* Tabs */}
        {user ? (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="HomeTabs" component={Tabs} />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Profile"
              component={Profile}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="ChatBot"
              component={ChatBot}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="ExpertHome"
              component={ExpertHome}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="CourseList"
              component={CourseList}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />

            <Stack.Screen
              name="Cources"
              component={Cources}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="IntroductionAnimationScreen"
              component={IntroductionAnimationScreen}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Settings"
              options={{
                headerShown: false,
                cardStyleInterpolator: ({ current, next, layouts }) => {
                  return {
                    cardStyle: {
                      transform: [
                        {
                          translateX: current.progress.interpolate({
                            inputRange: [0, 1],
                            outputRange: [layouts.screen.width, 0],
                          }),
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                    overlayStyle: {
                      opacity: current.progress.interpolate({
                        inputRange: [0, 1],
                        outputRange: [0, 0.5],
                      }),
                    },
                  };
                },
              }}
              component={Settings}
            />
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            {/* Screens */}
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Welcome"
              component={Welcome}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Signup"
              component={Signup}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Login"
              component={Login}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
          </>
        )}
        <Stack.Screen
          name="PlantDetail"
          component={PlantDetail}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here are all my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@google-ai/generativelanguage": "^1.1.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.2.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "expo": "~49.0.5",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "firebase": "^10.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "postcss": "8.4.23",
    "prop-types": "*",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-heroicons": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-modalize": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-onboarding-swiper": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-progress-circle": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.5.4",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
```

And Here is the `AppEntry.js` file (if needed):

```
import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';

import App from '../../App';

registerRootComponent(App);
```

I've tried doing the following:

1. Deleting the `node_modules` and reinstalling it with `yarn` (or `npm install`).
2. Checking all the dependencies that have any issues in terms of `import/export`.
3. Checking the syntax for each and every screen that I'm importing into `App.js` 
   (especially how I export them).

Comment: Looks like an ESM vs. commonjs issue – your ESM is not being transpiled down to commonjs, despite some build step or service expecting it to be. Are you targeting the right platform?

Comment: It's weird that it complains about `export` in a file that doesn't even contain that keyword. Perhaps some build steps are out of order or stepping on each other's toes... because that `export` must come from _somewhere_ and I'm guessing it comes from a previous build step.

Comment: @Henke sure. Although the error has already been resolved here is the bable file:
```
module.exports = function async (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ["nativewind/babel", "react-native-reanimated/plugin"],
  };
};
```

Comment: How did you resolve the error?
[You can answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).
(And therefore you can earn reputation on the answer as well as on the question.)
Please consider adding a "self-answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for taking your precious times for this problem. But I've solved this problem. Here are the things I did:

Okay, So because I was using TS with JS and that's why the error occurred between Common JS & ES modules. To remove this :

1. I changed the babel.config.js into this:

```js
module.exports = function async (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ["nativewind/babel", "react-native-reanimated/plugin"],
  };
};
```

2. Then I deleted my node_modules and package.json (please make a copy before deleting it) files. And I reinstalled all the dependencies one by one using yarn.
   This error was occurring because of the conflict on export in any of my dependencies. So, after I reinstalled them one by one, the error was resolved automatically.

> Here is why I think that it happened because of error in export of any
> of my dependencies:
>
> I went to AppEntry.js and I found that `import App from '../../App';`
> in this line, AppEntry was unable to find the App.js file. So, then I
> checked the App.js thoroughly. And I found that there was nothing
> unnatural inside the `return()`. So, the error must be present in any
> of the dependencies that I've used in this project.

**Another thing, try using yarn rather using npm. Yarn installs the dependencies as per their required versions.**

Answer (score 0):

1. When I got a similar error yesterday,

```
Android Bundling failed
error: node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js: Unexpected token ']'
```

[image: error: node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js: Unexpected token.]

it turned out I had a syntax error in `babel.config.js`.

2. Another approach would be to start a completely new project, 
     [`npx create-expo-app name-of-the-new-app`](https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/create-your-first-app) 
   and then move your code files over to the new project, one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue by read docs in https://docs.expo.dev/develop/unit-testing/,
so, I change my jest.config.js to below like, and finnally fix it, it you have any module import throw error, just add it to fields "transformIgnorePatterns":

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-expo',
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg|@rneui/base)"
  ]
};
```